# Kibana Unable to revive connection to ElasticSearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, kibana

I am new to ElasticSearch, I was following the instruction here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

Whenever I run 'docker-compose up', Kibana would always say "Unable to revive connection", but if I run curl http://localhost:9200, I will get a response:

```json
{
  "name" : "ec88fa675367",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "UkLkAHO8S4yzAKFaf0KsYA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "e9ccaed468e2fac2275a3761849cbee64b39519f",
    "build_date" : "2019-11-26T01:06:52.518245Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml, please help, thanks!

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  elastic:

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0
    container_name: kibana
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://localhost:9200
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it isn't working is because you are setting `ELASICSEARCH_HOSTS` as the Kibana host (as localhost represents the kibana container). What you need to do is use the elasticsearch hostname `ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200`.

You also need to map your Kibana port or else you won't be able to reach it from your local machine (similarly what you have done for elasticsearch).

The example below should work:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  elastic:

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.0
    container_name: kibana
    networks:
      - elastic
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://elasticsearch:9200
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
```